# Angular ngStorage not working in my angular page?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm beginning to learn more about angular and wanted to add in ngstorage to my application.

Here's what it looks like in the app.js:

```
angular.module('AppName', ['ngStorage']).controller('local_storage', function($scope, $localStorage, $sessionStorage){
     $scope.$storage = $localStorage.$default({
        user_id: 5,
        handle: 'user_default_handle'
    });
}); 
var app = angular.module('AppName', []);
app.controller('SomeController', function() {
//....Some stuff here
});
```

While here is what it looks like in the page itself:

```
<div class="navigation" ng-controller="local_storage" ng-cloak>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="home.html"><i class="fa fa-home"></i></a></li>
                <li><a href="search.html"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></a></li>
                <li><a href="camera.html"><i class="fa fa-camera-retro"></i></a></li>
                <li><a ng-href="profile.html#/?id={{$storage.user_id}}"><i class="fa fa-street-view"></i></a></li>
                <li><a href="messages.html"><i class="fa fa-inbox"></i></a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
```

However on the actual page, the link will default to:
profile.html#/?id={{$storage.user_id}}

More Things to note:

The page app is "AppName"
the behavior happens on non links as well for the storage.

It could be that I misunderstand how to declare ngstorage or something, but I'm not so sure.

Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Problem soled, I was trying to be stubborn, when i could have just added them all to the same module "app" and then made sure to include them on each page.

I was initially trying to find a way to include the js on only the pages that needed it but thats a micro-optimization at best.